# Is it possible to use a service account with Git-Secrets?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services

I would like to scan my private git repos with git-secrets to catch any aws keys that may be accidentally committed.
I personally am not a developer, so is it possible to use a service account or something that logs into the repos to scan with this tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`awslabs/git-secrets`](https://github.com/awslabs/git-secrets) is only a scanner.

Which means it does not clone/access a repo.
It is registered within an existing cloned repo, where it will operate, ensuring that you are not committing sensitive data.
Or where it will scan the past history of, again, an existing cloned repo with `git secrets --scan-history`.

So you can clone said repo with any credentials you want, including a service account.
Or even [multiple AWS accouts](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-git-with-aws-codecommit-across-multiple-aws-accounts/) when using [AWS CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/) to host your private Git repositories.

Once cloned, then you can scan them.